# Initialize libraries in Application using RxJava async

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to avoid overloading the Application class with initializing libs but sometimes is not possible.
So, what I thought was:
start them all asynchronous and just use them in the activities after started. Also, I would like to know how can I do that with RxJava.

For instance:

```
class App extends Application {
   public void onCreate(){
     Realm.init();
     Fresco.init();
     Retrofit.init(); // just example.
     // etc
   }
}

class MyActivity extends Activity{
   public void onCreate(){
     realm.where(SomeClass.class).findAll(); 
   }
}
```

This way it's synchronous (obviously), but how can I achieve it asynchronous and have it guaranteed that the libs will only run after App. has finished loading them?

Comment: You can use a singleton pattern and then access the resource using the singleton pattern each time. This will init the resource the first time it is requested and will then use the same resource the next time. You could also maybe use dagger. It depends on what is needed by realm and fresco from the application class. It might just be the application context.

Comment: I already use dagger for some cases, can it be async?

Comment: From my understanding, dagger does not initialize resources until they are requested.

Comment: Not all calls can be async, and when async you will have to check the state of every usage

Comment: Ops.. You are correct, but, what I was thinking is: initialize them before so I don't need to wait when I really need it, but, I can't use main thread for this. I agree that I would need to check the stage, that's why I thought that RxJava could help.